# LWC: Add a region in custom community theme

Tags: community, lightning-community, community-builder, lightning-web-components, template

I would like to add a region in my custom community theme.
For now I am only able to add my LWC components in the body area and would like to know how I can declare regions in my theme to accept LWC (with parameter recordId).

For now I am using something like this

```
<aura:attribute name="navBar" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false" />
```

When I drop the component in the custom area, the component is shown in the builder but disappear as soon as I refresh the builder or when I go on the page after publishing.

When I drop my component in the body area (default one I guess), the components are displayed normally.

The problem appears when I am using a recordId that I pass in the parameters of the component (in the builder).
When adding a component that's not using a parameter, it is shown as expected.

On the page, this error is shown on the console:

```
aura_proddebug.js:46007 WARNING: $A.eventService.addHandler: Unknown component with globalId 'undefined'. Does this component exist?
```

If I cut the parameter {!recordId}, press enter (so param changes), paste the parameter back in and press enter, my content is shown until I refresh the builder...

I couldn't find any documentation on this.

Thank you !